# Does it take 24 hours for custom events to be recorded in Parse Analytics

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse and I've just tried adding a basic event with data like so:

```
NSDictionary *dimensions = @{
                             // What type of news is this?
                             @"category": @"politics",
                             // Is it a weekday or the weekend?
                             @"dayType": @"weekday",
                             };

[PFAnalytics trackEvent:@"read" dimensions:dimensions];
```

From the dashboard I can see the API Request event recorded but I can't seem to access the specific event or data. Does it take 24 hours to register or am I using the dashboard incorrectly?

Answer (score 16):

Ok, I think I've found the issue. You won't see it in the Dashboard unless you click on "Custom Breakdown" and then select from the options to visualize your custom event, then use the filters to see the dimensions for "category" and "dayType" from the Filters inside of it.

If you want to keep this report for future use then click "Save Breakdown" and you can always come back to it (although you can't edit the filters)
I hope this helps.

Comment: For anyone else that couldn't find the "Custom breakdown" button, click on events then click on the round button (usually says API requests) that's above the graph.  It can be a little tricky to find.  You'll see "Custom breakdown" when you click on it.

Comment: In "Events" you click on the "Analytics" Tab, and then click the button that should read "API Requests" and at the bottom you should see a button with a plus sign and the "Custom Breakdown" text.