# Parse analytics custom event not registering

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Both of these commands register as analytics events but I can't see a breakdown of the custom event names.

```
PFAnalytics.trackEventInBackground("ML Feeling Bad", block: nil)
```

--

```
var dictionary = ["test" : "val"]
PFAnalytics.trackEventInBackground("ML Feeling Good", dimensions: dictionary, block: nil)
```

I'm looking at Analytics > Events > Analytics Requests. Custom Breakdown doesn't seem to have any helpful options.

Answer (score 2):

I've just found! Remove the **spaces** in events names.

For example change `"ML Feeling Good"` to `"MLFeelingGood"`

Seems that there is a bug inside Parse Analytics, because events with spaces are displayed in Explorer, but not in Analytics tab. And events with no spaces are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time to show Custom event we have registered as pointed out in this link also.

[Does it take 24 hours for custom events to be recorded in Parse Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700578/does-it-take-24-hours-for-custom-events-to-be-recorded-in-parse-analytics)

If u want to see your custom event then u can select  Analytics > Events > Analytics Requests > Custom Breakdown and then in Custom BreakDown section you have to select **read** option from the drop down to see your event which u have registered.

[image: Select Custom BreakDown Option]
[image: Select read Option]

Once you have selected read option you must be able to see your event which was Test in my case it is Category and dayType.
Just select your event and turn it on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: PFAnalytics.trackEventInBackground("ML Feeling Good", dimensions: dictionary);  try this out

Answer (score 1):

I am using

```
PFAnalytics.trackEvent("video", dimensions:["title": self.title])
```

with success (and with the mandatory PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions) in the implementation of AppDelegate)

Anyway, in the Parse doc about trackEventInBackground:dimensions:block: they say:

> block: The block to execute on server response. It should have the
>   following argument signature: ^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)

So maybe you cannot set the block to nil.
I hope this helps!